# Отсутствует перевод в «настройки почты»

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, мобильная-версия

Отсутствует перевод в [«настройки почты»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current) (доступно только в мобильной версии сайта)

> [image]

Comment: Тут интереснее почему этой опции нет в полной версии сайта. Задал [вопросик](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356334/339911) на MSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил перевод для описания

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13207

Для заголовка не добавлял, т.к. это по сути [название блога](https://stackoverflow.blog/newsletter/).

Будет на сайте в новых ревизиях. Текущая  rev 2020.11.10.37978